# dynamodb filtering on values NOT IN a list

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to use the NOT operator on a dynamodb scan filter

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name dev-users \
--select SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES \
--projection-expression id \
--filter-expression "address.#state IN (:s1, :s2, :s3, :s4)" \
--expression-attribute-names '{"#state": "state"}' \
--expression-attribute-values '{ ":s1": { "S": "ND" }, ":s2": { "S": "CA" }, ":s3": { "S": "IL" }, ":s4": { "S": "VT" } }'
```

However, it doesn't work.  IN by itself does work.  What am I missing?

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Scan operation: Invalid FilterExpression: Syntax error; token: "NOT", near: "#state NOT IN"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is exactly what DynamoDB's error message told you: you are using the wrong syntax.... You should refer to Amazon's documentation about FilterExpression syntax - here is a link to the right place: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html

In your case, there is no operator "NOT IN". But you can put a "NOT" on the entire condition, i.e., `NOT address.#state IN (:s1, :s2, :s3, :s4)`.